# Marquee notification loses focus and stops when another notification comes in

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have an ongoing notification with a horizontal marquee defined by:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="52dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:singleLine="true" >
            <requestFocus />
        </TextView>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and

```
fun createNotificationChannel(context: Context) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val name = "channel_name"
        val descriptionText = "channel_description"
        val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        val channel = NotificationChannel("CHANNEL_ID", name, importance).apply {
            description = descriptionText
        }

        // Register the channel with the system
        val notificationManager: NotificationManager =
            context.applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }
}
```

```
suspend fun showNotification(context: Context) {
    var collapsedView = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.default_notification_collapsed)
    collapsedView.setTextViewText(
                R.id.text,
                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.")

    val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context.applicationContext, "CHANNEL_ID")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
        .setCustomContentView(collapsedView)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
        .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
        .setOngoing(true)

    with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(context.applicationContext)) {
        notify(1, builder.build())
    }
}
```

This works on Oreo just fine but when a notification comes in from another app, the marquee stops on the lock screen.  This seems to happen on notifications from Gmail and Twitter but not on system notifications like "open wifi detected".

Also, it doesn't seem to happen right away.  When a new notification comes in, it appears above my ongoing notification (the marquee continues scrolling) and after a few seconds, android rearranges the notifications so my ongoing notification appears on top and the marquee stops.

Is this expected behaviour? How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Why are you showing a marquee in the first place? Isn't that bad accessibility as it can be hard for users who may not be able to read as quickly as the text scrolls past?

Comment: My app requires it, I imagine there are many applications for it like stock tickers or scrolling long song names on a music app

Comment: what logcat say when this happen?

Comment: I'm not sure what to look for but I staged a little test with the app running and I sent a test email to the device.  This is what I got:  https://pastebin.com/5Dx1MTQH